# Create IF conditional inside SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to test the resilience of my app, which is deployed in OpenShift along with other apps.

I created a non-static variable in my application.yaml called response

```
response: 1
```

I have the SpringBootApplication ready to run

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccountApplication {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountApplication.class, args);
      }
}
```

What I want to do, is create a conditional inside the static void to choose if I run the app or not.
I tried with

```
public class AccountApplication {
        @Value("${response}") private int response;
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(response==1){
         SpringApplication.run(AccountApplication.class, args);
       }else{}  
      }
}
```

But I cant use a non-static variable inside an static method. Tried to change my variable to non-static using this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field , but the value was always 0.

How can I do it?
I just want an environment variable so I can choose wether my app starts or not to the the resiliency of the other apps.

Comment: What is the reason you want to check it? Normally you can use the actuator-endpoint (health) to check if a spring service is running on a IP:PORT. If you just use a application internal variable you cant notice if other apps are running. You need to use the external check mechanism.

Comment: I just want to decide if my app fails or not, and test its resiliency with ISTIO.

Answer (score 1):

If your target is to make the application fail to run based on the condition, then you can check that non-static value condition using `@PostConstruct` as below:

```
@Value("${static.class.value}")
private boolean doRun;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
}


@PostConstruct
private void stopApplication() {
    if (!doRun) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Application forcefully stopped as stopValue in application.properties is true");
    }
}
```

The application will exit with throwing this exception if the `doRun` is `false`